# backbone routes with jqMobi

Tags: backbone.js, jqmobi

I've been porting my backbone app to use jqMobi and jqUI for the interface.

Originally, I wasn't getting anything from my backbone router, I couldn't even output to the console, routes were being completely ignored.

I moved the `backbone.init()` function into the ui.js `init` function, and the routes are now being triggered, but I get the errors

```
 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

from this route

```
edit:  function(id){
        alert('triggered');
         $.ui.setTitle('temp title');
        $.ui.loadContent('edit',false,false,'slide');

      new MyApp.Views.EditUser(id);

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ui.loadContent('edi',false,false,'slide');
```

Is "edi" the correct id of the panel you are trying to load?

Comment: That was a typing mistake in stackoverflow @ian, the code is referencing the correct panel id.

Comment: I'm the lead dev on jqMobi, so I'd be more then happy to help you figure this out.  Would it be possible to see a demo of it failing?  You can get my email from my github page.

Comment: thanks @Ian, I don't have anything public yet, but hopefully next week, and I'll ping you then. I've worked around it for now.

Comment: Ok...If you can also isolate it to a small example, I'll be happy to look at that too.